# for loop pulling through Array in to table

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, loop, array

I'm trying to build a loop that goes through a field that contains multiple labels and values, the outputs are not correct and I can't figure out why. can anyone help?

```ampscript
%%[
SET @str = "label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w|label:c,value:y"
SET @strRS = BuildRowsetfromString(@str,"|")

FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@strRS) DO
  SET @row = Row(@strRS,@i)
  SET @string = Field(@row,1)
  
  SET @RS2 = BuildRowsetfromString(@string, ",")
  
  FOR @a=1 TO Rowcount(@RS2) DO
 if MOD(@a,2) > 0 THEN
    SET @label = Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1)
 ELSE
     SET @value = Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1)

ENDIF
 
  ]%%
<br><br>----------------------<br><br>
String = %%=v(@string)=%%<br>


<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td width="50px" height="50px">Image</td>
      <td>label</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="50px" height="50px"><img src="#" width="50px" height="50px" alt=""/></td>
      <td>%%=v(@label)=%%</td>
      <td>%%=v(@value)=%%</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

%%[
  NEXT @a
NEXT @i
]%%
```

Output:

```
----------------------

String = label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w
    label   value
    label:a 

----------------------

String = label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w
    label   value
    label:a value:x

----------------------

String = label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w
    label   value
    lable:b value:x

----------------------

String = label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w
    label   value
    lable:b value:w
```

Comment: You really should know how to apply formatting to your questions by now.

Comment: What's not correct about the output?  https://i.imgur.com/U9yUkQG.png

Comment: Hi Adam,

I wasn't expecting the first table as it doesn't contain both the label and value. In the 3rd table it has the wrong value it's ahowing x instead of w

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are outputting is correct in what is coded, but that is not the output you actually intended to code for. I am assuming you just want the output to be once per label/value combination.

To achieve that, I would adjust your code to include some conditionals to only output on even iterative numbers and to clear the label/value after output.

Something like below should work:

```
%%[
SET @str = "label:a,value:x, lable:b,value:w|label:c,value:y"
SET @strRS = BuildRowsetfromString(@str,"|")

FOR @i=1 TO Rowcount(@strRS) DO
  SET @row = Row(@strRS,@i)
  SET @string = Field(@row,1)
  
  SET @RS2 = BuildRowsetfromString(@string, ",")
  
  FOR @a=1 TO Rowcount(@RS2) DO
    if MOD(@a,2) > 0 THEN
        SET @label = Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1)
    ELSE
         SET @value = Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1)
    ENDIF
 
 if MOD(@a,2) == 0 THEN
]%%


<br><br>----------------------<br><br>
String = %%=v(@string)=%%<br>


<table width="300" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
  <td width="50px" height="50px">Image</td>
      <td>label</td>
      <td>value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td width="50px" height="50px"><img src="#" width="50px" height="50px" alt=""/></td>
      <td>%%=v(@label)=%%</td>
      <td>%%=v(@value)=%%</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

%%[
  
    SET @label = ""
    SET @value = ""
  ENDIF

  NEXT @a
NEXT @i
]%%
```

**Output**:
[image]

and if you want to remove the 'label:' and 'value:' prepends from your output string, you could just use an AMPScript replace on it to remove them. Something like:

```
    if MOD(@a,2) > 0 THEN
        SET @label = Replace(Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1),"label:","")
    ELSE
         SET @value = Replace(Field(Row(@RS2,@a),1),"value:","")
    ENDIF
```

Comment: You could also use TRIM() to strip the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks, just adding a few other fields

Comment: @PeterHo - Sorry but I honestly have no idea what you mean by that.